# I get page not found (404) error when going to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/restaurant/sign-in/" page

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

When I go to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/restaurant/sign-in/" I get page not found (404) error. But I can go to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/restaurant/$" to access the home page.

I also tried "http://127.0.0.1:8000/restaurant/sign-in/$" but this also gives me error (init() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given).

My urls.py is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from foodtaskerapp import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('restaurant/sign-in/$', auth_views.LoginView,
         {'template_name': 'restaurant/sign_in.html'},
         name='restaurant-sign-in'),
    path('restaurant/sign-out', auth_views.LogoutView,
         {'next_page': '/'},
         name='restaurant-sign-out'),
    path('restaurant/$', views.restaurant_home, name='restaurant- 
         home'),
]
```

And my views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def home(request):
    return redirect(restaurant_home)

def restaurant_home(request):
    return render(request, 'restaurant/home.html', {})
```

[here is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyDT0.png)

I also have

```
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

in sign_in.html but the form don't show up, only Sign In is shown.
[only sign is shown but not the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCJPW.png)

Comment: OP wants to use standard Auth views. Why would you suggest implementing custom views for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no corresponding function in views.py:
auth_views.LoginView
Also, i guess, you neither have 'restaurant/sign_in.html', so it doesn't redirect to the page.

---

Add this in views.py:

```
def restaurant_signIn(request):
    return render(request, 'restaurant/sign_in.html')
```

And corresponding HTML page name: 'sign_in.html',in restaurant directory:

```
<p>SigninWorks</p>
```

---

Your urls.py must look like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from foodtaskerapp import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('restaurant/sign-in/', views.restaurant_signIn,
         name='restaurant-sign-in'),
    path('restaurant/$', views.restaurant_home, name='restaurant- 
         home'),
]
```

Answer (score 3):

the syntax for the function you are using has changed in the latest version of django, which is why you got that error (the code you are sharing is in a tutorial made by code4startups which uses an older version of django).
You should modify your path command to:

```
path('restaurant/sign-in/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
       template_name='restaurant/sign_in.html'),
       name='restaurant-sign-in'),
```

Comment: I meant the answer by Ganesh Jadhav is wrong. He wants to use the function provided by django (auth_views) therefore he doesn't need to modify the views.py file in his project. He was just using functions whose syntax has changed.

Comment: I am certain because i am following the same tutorial myself and ran into the same problem. After modifying the syntax to the latest version of django, everything worked flawlessly just liked in the tutorial.

Comment: Tomas Mendoza. With the information you provided in the comment, this now seems to be a decent answer (please [edit] to collect everthing in the answer itself). I hence deleted my "questioning" comments. Good work reacting and taking the feedback. Please understand however, that in the actual technical matter I am not knowledgable enough to decide on an upvote. Good luck and thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 Please excuse me for drawing your attention again. The post might be worth assessing again (no matter whether you did or did not vote already).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @Yunnosch, I indeed voted and flagged. Removed both and upvoted (+1) to support the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your effort guys. Coming back just to change your initial votes is what makes stackoverflow great.

Comment: Thank you, Tomas Mendoza for the answer.